# "Column not found" when joining table in SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm new in spring boot and now I'm trying to joining two tables where one of them are composite table (idk if it's have any effect or not). Please take a look on my code and help me.

**Employees.java (Model)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employees {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_no")
    private long emp_no;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

**Salaries.java (Model, The composite table)**

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "salaries")
public class Salaries {

    @Column(name = "emp_no") //Primary Key
    private long emp_no;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private int salary;
    
    @Column(name = "date") //Primary Key
    private LocalDate date;
}
```

**EmployeeRepo.java (Repository)**

```js
public interface EmployeesRepository extends JpaRepository<Employees, Long> {

    String salary = "SELECT employees.name, salaries.salary FROM employees INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no=salaries.emp_no LIMIT 0,10";
    @Query(value=salary, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employees> getUserSalary();

}
```

**EmpController.java (Controller)**

```js
@GetMapping("/salary")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employees>> getSalaries(@RequestParam(required = false) String args){
        List<Employees> employees = new ArrayList<Employees>();

        employeesRepository.getUserSalary().forEach(employees::add);

        if(employees.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**application.properties**

```js
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/employees?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= ""
spring.datasource.password= ""

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

And the error message:

> Column 'emp_no' not found.

I dont understand why I get this error when I have `emp_no` column both on my tables in db.

Comment: check if you have connection to the same DB in properties, Also post table structure if possible.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS i added the application.properties, and for table structure, It's just that one employees have many salaries if it's what you're asking.

Comment: if you are using phpmyadmin or mysql workbench there will be option to create auto generate select query or insert query check if any space or special char in table column name.

Comment: but when i tried the query in phpmyadmin, it works well

Comment: just capitalize the query and try if that helps

Comment: @PavanKumarTS nothing is change:(

Comment: ok then try individual table select in spring and identify which table is not recognising column

Comment: @PavanKumarTS ok, so, when I tried run to get salaries I got error: "Cannot invoke "com.hqm.demoapi.repository.SalariesRepository.findAll()" because "this.salariesRepository" is null"

But what I don't get it is my EmployeesRepo not having anything in the interface (excepet the query) and it still works?

Comment: if you have findAll overwriten in salariesRepository change name .

Comment: @PavanKumarTS but my SalariesRepository doesn't have any function in it?

Comment: @PavanKumarTS hey, idk if you're still hre or not, but, I finally get data from the salaries table, but when I join it, still get the same error

Comment: Its simple, You are trying to fetch and use data from employees and salaries tables, but in form clause you have just mentioned employees and missing salaries. Just add salaries table as well after from clause and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem  is

```
 String salary = "SELECT employees.name, salaries.salary FROM employees INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no=salaries.emp_no LIMIT 0,10";
 @Query(value=salary, nativeQuery = true)
 List<Employees> getUserSalary();
```

you are trying to save name,salary in Employees which only has emp_no, name. So the error is sating you have mapped name but emp_no is not available from query.
Create POJO/model like below

```
public class EmpSalary {
    private String name;
    private double salary;
}
```

Then update your repository to return EmpSalary

```
String salary = "SELECT employees.name, salaries.salary FROM employees INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no=salaries.emp_no LIMIT 0,10";
@Query(value=salary, nativeQuery = true)
List<EmpSalary> getUserSalary();
```